# Ubuntu 18.04 Xfce - Have to login twice

Tags: 18.04, login

First question here, as I've been using Linux for about 2 weeks now.

I've encountered nothing but problems and after a lot of unsuccessful searching I decided I should start asking.

**Current main issue**

When I login, either after booting or logging out, I have to login twice.
After the first time I login, I get to see this for maybe 1 second:
[Screen_after_first_login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afCDD.jpg)

After that it returns to the login screen, where I enter my password again and then it successfully logs in.
Besides being annoying, this makes me think there's something wrong under the hood.
So I'd like to fix it.

**This is my setup**

- Mobo: Asus TRX40 Creator
- CPU: AMD Ryzen TR 3960X
- GPU: nVidia 2080Ti

**Full story** (in case there are things that have something to do with this)

During my first install two weeks ago, I had to add "mce=off" to my kernel boot parameters.
Due to an [issue with 3900X processors](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Boot-Threadripper-Zen2MCE)
After that everything went relatively smooth, except for not being able to connect to the internet via Ethernet cable.
So I just used the Wifi, which seemd to work with no problems.
Until I started messing around with VPN settings and what-not, in an attempt to connect to a forticlient VPN.
I tried numerous "solution", not knowing what I was doing, and eventually all of a sudden my Wifi stopped working.
Constantly losing connection, connecting, losing connection, etc...
After looking around, not finding a solution, I figured I messed around too much.
Not knowing what to fix, I decided to do a clean install.
That's where I'm at now.

- I have the double login thing going (current main issue, I guess)
- I didn't need the mce=off thing anymore for some reason
- Wired internet is working fine, wifi isn't
- My audio is crackling and giving static
- I'm getting a "system program problem detected" after every login (probably the audio)
- And all my additional hard drives and their folders and files now have a lock icon on them...

I'm kind of stumped and pretty exhausted after all of this.

So I'm hoping somebody is able to help out.

The disk with Linux on it has no important files, so I'm able to completely wipe/format/clean it if necessary.

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `tail -f /var/log/syslog` keep an eye on that log for any error messages or anything that might help. If you find something, edit your question and include it here. To cancel the syslog just type CTRL + c.

Comment: @Pilot6 Uuuug, update graphics drivers solved the issues of double login and the audio crackling is also gone.
I must be really exhausted as I remember this to be one of the first things I did after my first install.

Comment: @Parto So far, it's not showing any error messages. But thanks for the tip!